# How to use XSLT 1.0 to convert UTF8 4-digits representation back to the original charset?

Tags: xslt, oracle11g

I'm writing a PL/SQL tool for Oracle to get an XML Spreadsheet out from a cursor.

After a few days I've come to the conclusion that the simplest way to get it done is just relay on the XML features the Oracle DB offers.

So, my idea is just to format the query result in XML and then get an Excel Spreadsheet via XSLT.

So far, so good: I managed to get my spreadsheet from the query I wrote but I need to solve a little issue.

I want the ability to set the column headings in Excel just setting aliases on my columns, but when I use characters not compliant with the XML language I obviously get something different from what I mean.

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
'select first_name as "First na/Me" 
   from hr.employees
  where department_id = 100;') from dual;
```

generates:

```
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <First_x0020_na_x002F_Me>Nancy</First_x0020_na_x002F_Me>
 </ROW>
<ROWSET>
```

Nothing prevents me from getting my Excel though, I then transform the XML document above via XSLT to an Excel 2007 compatible workbook containing this node

```
<Cell>
 <Data ss:Type="String">First_x0020_na_x002F_Me</Data>
</Cell>
```

At this point I just need to instruct my XSLT ti search in the column headings for "*x\uFFFF*", extract the hexadecimal code and turn it into the corresponding character, but how can this be done?

As mentioned in the title, my XSLT is 1.0 compliant <strike>but I can upgrade to an upper version if necessary</strike> and I cannot upgrade due to unsupported native support for XSLT 2.0 in Oracle DB.

Comment: "*my XSLT is 1.0 compliant but in can upgrade*" I believe you would be much happier using XSLT 2.0 with its support for the `codepoints-to-string()` function (as well as other functions that make string processing much easier).

Comment: I'll take a look to that and see if I can get the things done.

Comment: @Max I should add that this *can* be done in XSLT 1.0 - provided you have a finite list of the characters that may need restoring. But it still will be rather awkward to do without the benefit of regex support.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I just found out Oracle 11gR2 does not support XSLT 2.0 internally. It would be possible to wrap a Java XSLT 2.0 processor, but I'd like to get the things done just using Oracle native features. So I need to investigate a different approach.

Comment: @Max, Then you will need to add your-written extension function that takes an integer and uses it as a Unicode code-value to return the character that corresponds to that value -- essentially the same thing that the standard XPath 2.0 function `codepoints-to-string()` is doing. If you can create this extension function, then I will give you the rest of the XSLT 1.0 transformation.

Comment: @Max Do you have a list of the characters that may need restoring? I presume you do not use Greek, Arabic or Chinese characters in your column names. If you can reduce such list to a manageable size, you can then lookup from it, and avoid the need for more elaborate processing.

Comment: MUCH LATER: For an XSLT 3.0 solution and a (limited) XSLT 1.0 solution, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78124222/xslt-select-of-decode-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At this point I just need to instruct my XSLT to search in the column
>   headings for "x\uFFFF", extract the hexadecimal code and turn it into
>   the corresponding character, but how can this be done?
>
> As mentioned in the title, my XSLT is 1.0 compliant but in can upgrade
>   to an upper version if necessary.

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[matches(., '_x(\d|[A-Fa-f]){4}_')]">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="_x((\d|[A-Fa-f]){{4}})_" >
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="codepoints-to-string(my:hex-to-int(regex-group(1), 0))"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="my:hex-to-int" as="xs:integer">
    <xsl:param name="pHex" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="pResult" as="xs:integer"/>

    <xsl:sequence select=
    "if(not($pHex))
       then $pResult
       else
         my:hex-to-int(substring($pHex, 2), 
                       16*$pResult + my:hex-digit-to-int(substring($pHex, 1, 1)))
    "/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="my:hex-digit-to-int" as="xs:integer">
    <xsl:param name="pHexDigit" as="xs:string"/>

    <xsl:sequence select=
       "index-of(string-to-codepoints('0123456789abcdef'), 
                 string-to-codepoints(lower-case($pHexDigit)))[1] -1"/>
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Cell xmlns:ss="some:ss">
    <Data ss:Type="String">First_x0020_na_x002F_Me</Data>
</Cell>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Cell xmlns:ss="some:ss">
      <Data ss:Type="String">First na/Me</Data>
</Cell>
```

**Note**:

A similar solution in XSLT 1.0 would be possible, if we could use an extension function that takes an integer and returns the Unicode character that has as its code this integer -- exactly what the XPath 2.0 `codepoints-to-string()` function is doing.

**As for escaping "unsafe HTML characters",** just specifying:

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>
```

should ensure that the unsafe characters are represented properly.

Comment: That would have been great, but unfortunately I found out XSLT 2.0 is not natively supported by Oracle, so I cannot rely on your awesome solution. Furthermore I just realize my initial requirements are not correct: what if in the string appears a "<" sign? That requires to be escaped. I have no idea how your solution will handle this (I haven't tested it). By the way, I'm closing this post accepting your solution as proper to the question.

Comment: @Max, I will be glad to help in the future, whenever you have further developed your requirements.

Comment: @Max, Re: "what if in the string appears a "<" sign? That requires to be escaped." In case you could use XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0), there is the standard XPath function: **escape-html-uri()**, **http://w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-escape-html-uri** and this function, among other things, escapes unsafe (for HTML) characters. Or you may not need such escaping if the output method is "html" -- this should be done by the XSLT serialization. Also, if such characters appear in your source XML document, some or all of them will be already escaped, as required by the lexical rules for well-formed XML