# XSLT Select of decode values

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my XML Sample.  Looks like the values are encoded.
I am creating  sample xslt template like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="fee_number"/>
```

how do I decode values so that they are presented normally?
Thanks.

```
<fees>
  <fee>
    <fee_number>_x0031_645111</fee_number>
    <fee_type>Property_x0020_Registration_x0020_Fee</fee_type>
    <fee_issued_date>_x0030_1_x002F_01_x002F_2023</fee_issued_date>
    <fee_amount>_x0024_13.00</fee_amount>
    <fee_transfer_date>_x0030_5_x002F_12_x002F_2023</fee_transfer_date>
    <fee_transfer_status>Yes</fee_transfer_status>
  </fee>
  <fee>
    <fee_number>_x0031_459853</fee_number>
    <fee_type>Property_x0020_Registration_x0020_Fee</fee_type>
    <fee_issued_date>_x0030_1_x002F_01_x002F_2022</fee_issued_date>
    <fee_amount>_x0024_13.00</fee_amount>
    <fee_transfer_date>_x0030_5_x002F_16_x002F_2022</fee_transfer_date>
    <fee_transfer_status>Yes</fee_transfer_status>
  </fee>
</fees>
```

Comment: What is the "normal" presentation of a value like `_x0031_645111`?

Comment: It would be 1645111

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs to do this in **pure XSLT 1.0, with no extensions**, here is a relatively simple way - provided some assumptions are true, namely:

1. Every code starts with `"_x00"` (i.e. all encoded characters are from
   the Extended ASCII charset);
2. There are no occurrences of `"_x00"` in the text except at the start
   of a code;
3. The output method is XML or HTML;
4. The XSLT processor supports `disable-output-escaping`;
5. The XSLT processor does the serializing (IOW, the output goes directly to a file).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="decode">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="decode">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '_x00')">
            <!-- text before -->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, '_x00')"/>
            <!-- decode -->
            <xsl:variable name="hex" select="substring-before(substring-after($text, '_x00'), '_')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('&amp;#x', $hex, ';')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            <!-- recursive call with text after -->
            <xsl:call-template name="decode">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after(substring-after($text, '_x00'), '_')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using the given input, the result here will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fees>
  <fee>
    <fee_number>&#x31;645111</fee_number>
    <fee_type>Property&#x20;Registration&#x20;Fee</fee_type>
    <fee_issued_date>&#x30;1&#x2F;01&#x2F;2023</fee_issued_date>
    <fee_amount>&#x24;13.00</fee_amount>
    <fee_transfer_date>&#x30;5&#x2F;12&#x2F;2023</fee_transfer_date>
    <fee_transfer_status>Yes</fee_transfer_status>
  </fee>
  <fee>
    <fee_number>&#x31;459853</fee_number>
    <fee_type>Property&#x20;Registration&#x20;Fee</fee_type>
    <fee_issued_date>&#x30;1&#x2F;01&#x2F;2022</fee_issued_date>
    <fee_amount>&#x24;13.00</fee_amount>
    <fee_transfer_date>&#x30;5&#x2F;16&#x2F;2022</fee_transfer_date>
    <fee_transfer_status>Yes</fee_transfer_status>
  </fee>
</fees>
```

which any conforming XML parser will read exactly the same as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fees>
  <fee>
    <fee_number>1645111</fee_number>
    <fee_type>Property Registration Fee</fee_type>
    <fee_issued_date>01/01/2023</fee_issued_date>
    <fee_amount>$13.00</fee_amount>
    <fee_transfer_date>05/12/2023</fee_transfer_date>
    <fee_transfer_status>Yes</fee_transfer_status>
  </fee>
  <fee>
    <fee_number>1459853</fee_number>
    <fee_type>Property Registration Fee</fee_type>
    <fee_issued_date>01/01/2022</fee_issued_date>
    <fee_amount>$13.00</fee_amount>
    <fee_transfer_date>05/16/2022</fee_transfer_date>
    <fee_transfer_status>Yes</fee_transfer_status>
  </fee>
</fees>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3.0 you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="parse-xml-fragment(replace(., '_(x[0-9A-F]*?)_', '&amp;#$1;'))" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fees>
   <fee>
      <fee_number>1645111</fee_number>
      <fee_type>Property Registration Fee</fee_type>
      <fee_issued_date>01/01/2023</fee_issued_date>
      <fee_amount>$13.00</fee_amount>
      <fee_transfer_date>05/12/2023</fee_transfer_date>
      <fee_transfer_status>Yes</fee_transfer_status>
   </fee>
   <fee>
      <fee_number>1459853</fee_number>
      <fee_type>Property Registration Fee</fee_type>
      <fee_issued_date>01/01/2022</fee_issued_date>
      <fee_amount>$13.00</fee_amount>
      <fee_transfer_date>05/16/2022</fee_transfer_date>
      <fee_transfer_status>Yes</fee_transfer_status>
   </fee>
</fees>
```

Stolen from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42110257/17153010

Answer (score 1):

If your XSLT processor supports extensibility via .Net c# language, you can write an XSLT along the following.

The `XmlConvert.DecodeName()` does its magic.

This approach will work even with XSLT 1.0

XSLT below is using **.Net XslCompiledTransform** XSLT processor that is conformant with the XSLT 1.0 standard.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    string var = "_x0031_645111";
    
    Console.Write(XmlConvert.DecodeName(var));
}
```

**Output**

```
1645111
```

**Input XML**

```
<fees>
    <fee>
        <fee_number>_x0031_645111</fee_number>
        <fee_type>Property_x0020_Registration_x0020_Fee</fee_type>
        <fee_issued_date>_x0030_1_x002F_01_x002F_2023</fee_issued_date>
        <fee_amount>_x0024_13.00</fee_amount>
        <fee_transfer_date>_x0030_5_x002F_12_x002F_2023</fee_transfer_date>
        <fee_transfer_status>Yes</fee_transfer_status>
    </fee>
    <fee>
        <fee_number>_x0031_459853</fee_number>
        <fee_type>Property_x0020_Registration_x0020_Fee</fee_type>
        <fee_issued_date>_x0030_1_x002F_01_x002F_2022</fee_issued_date>
        <fee_amount>_x0024_13.00</fee_amount>
        <fee_transfer_date>_x0030_5_x002F_16_x002F_2022</fee_transfer_date>
        <fee_transfer_status>Yes</fee_transfer_status>
    </fee>
</fees>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:csharp="urn:my-scripts"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl csharp">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="csharp:Decode(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="csharp"><![CDATA[
      public string Decode(string var)
      {
         return XmlConvert.DecodeName(var);
      }
   ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<fees>
  <fee>
    <fee_number>1645111</fee_number>
    <fee_type>Property Registration Fee</fee_type>
    <fee_issued_date>01/01/2023</fee_issued_date>
    <fee_amount>$13.00</fee_amount>
    <fee_transfer_date>05/12/2023</fee_transfer_date>
    <fee_transfer_status>Yes</fee_transfer_status>
  </fee>
  <fee>
    <fee_number>1459853</fee_number>
    <fee_type>Property Registration Fee</fee_type>
    <fee_issued_date>01/01/2022</fee_issued_date>
    <fee_amount>$13.00</fee_amount>
    <fee_transfer_date>05/16/2022</fee_transfer_date>
    <fee_transfer_status>Yes</fee_transfer_status>
  </fee>
</fees>
```

Comment: I believe this can work **only** in XSLT 1.0 - because what other processor besides  Microsoft supports writing a C# extension? You could probably do something similar in Java to work with Xalan. But that would also mean you'd be limited to XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, XmlPrime allows writing extension functions in C#, even compatible with the Microsoft namespace/mechanism. And Saxon .NET and SaxonCS also allow implementing (so called integrated) extension functions with C#, if needed/wanted. You can't embed your C# inline but as long as you can compile .NET code these processors allow both using XSLT 3 while doing calls into .NET code exposed as (integrated) extension functions.